# Grub will crash on motherboard with AMD onboard graphic card

Tags: grub2, amd-graphics

In Short: Grub crashes right at start on two mainboards with AMD onboard graphics.

How can I get grub not to crash?

I was using Ubuntu and kubuntu on a GA-880GA-Ud3H motherboard for a couple of years without problems. In December, I switched to a 64 bit version of Ubuntu.

Starting January 15th 2015, the computer crashed right after the POST. The screen turned purple and there was no response to keystrokes any more.
No message was displayed.
The same happened when using Uubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-amd64 installation DVD.

Other DVDs like Knoppix 7.2 or Rescatux 0.30.2 ran without problems.

**The only thing that helped was to install a PCIe graphic card (GT 9500 or Hd5450) and completly deactivate the onboard graphic card.**

An other motherboard with onboard graphic card , the FM2A88M Extreme4+ showed the same problem.

How can I get grub to work with onboard graphics on my machine?

Thing I tried without effect:

- Reinstallation of grub
- Firmware updates for motherboard and SSD
- Switched to an new motherboard
- Change of HDD/SDD
- Memtest was ok
- MD5 checksum of Ubuntu installation DVD checked and ok

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall the driver properly from the official AMD website. The driver puts its own entries into grub so it should fix the issue.